# How to protect my credentials on my clients website

Tags: database, wp-admin, login, password, microsoft

I work with many different clients and I know some will try other freelancers eventually. Right now, my password is stored in my clients database. Is there any way to make this process safe? I would rather not have different passwords for every single client. I do use Microsoft 365 and have Active Directory.

If I configure Active Directory login on my clients site, will they (or a tech-savvy future supplier of theirs) be able to gather any unique data in the database that will affect my Active Directory like a unique token or so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you say you have your password stored in your clients database what do you mean? If these are standard WordPress users then no WordPress does not store plaintext or encrypted passwords, it stores password hashes which cannot be reversed back into a normal password. Please edit your question with the edit link under the tags to make it clearer what you meant and to include _all_ the information relevant. Note that having the same password for every single client would reduce security not improve it

Comment: I'm not sure about ADS, but reusing passwords is never good. A sensible solution that avoids stored passwords is using OAUTH. This is achieved via plugin. One popular plugin us https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-login-with-eve-online-google-facebook/. Another is Automattic's own https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/

If you want passwordless login read this article https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-passwordless-login-in-wordpress-with-magic-links/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.